# Shift wheel down and rotate on center[Titanium]

Tags: image, rotation, titanium, geometry

I am working in Titanium developing a rotating wheel. I need to shift the wheel down from the default position of the image and then rotate the wheel on its new center(after shifting down).

How can I do that ?

This is the code I have written; but when I shift it down it doesn't rotate the new shifted center.

```
var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
   backgroundImage:'test.png',
   width: wheelWidth,
   height:wheelHeight,
   bottom:100
   anchorPoint:{x:0.5, y:0.5}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will rotate the image around its center 10 degrees.

```
var animation = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    anchorPoint : {x:0.5, y:0.5}, // Put this in only if on Android
    transform : Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(10), // amount of rotation
    duration : 2000 // Time this will take in milliseconds
});
image.animate(animation);
```